# Terraform for_each - where is each.key defined?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform-provider-azure

#### Expected Behaviour

I'm trying to better understand the for_each loop

Specifically where is the **each.key** value defined in the module call?
What would be an example of deploying 1 instance?  and then an example of multiple instances?
see  'Module call (parent module)' below

#### Actual Behavior

Not sure of expected outcome

#### Terraform (and AzureRM Provider) Version

#### Affected Resource(s)

- `azurerm_v2.41.0`
- `terraform v0.13.0`

#### Terraform Configuration Files

**Main.tf**

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "sql_mi" {
  for_each            = var.sql_mi_defaults
  
  name                = each.key # provide an example of how this is defined in module call?  # how would I deploy more than one instance?
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  deployment_mode     = var.deployment_mode
  template_content    = data.local_file.arm_template.content
  parameters_content  = <<PARAMETERS
     {
        "managedInstanceName": {
            "value": "${each.value.managedInstanceName}" 
        },
        "location": {
            "value": "${var.location}"
        },
        "skuName": {
            "value": "${each.value.skuName}"
        },
        "storageSizeInGB": {
            "value": "${each.value.storageSizeInGB}"
        },
        "vCores": {
            "value": "${each.value.vCores}"
        },
        "licenseType": {
            "value": "${each.value.licenseType}"
        },
        "collation": {
            "value": "${each.value.collation}"
        },
        "timezoneId": {
            "value": "${each.value.timezoneId}"
        },
        "collation": {
            "value": "${each.value.collation}"
        },
        "proxyOverride": {
            "value": "${each.value.proxyOverride}"
        },
        "publicDataEndpointEnabled": {
            "value": "${each.value.publicDataEndpointEnabled}"
        },
        "administratorLogin": {
            "value": "azadmin-${random_string.mi_name.result}"
        },
        "administratorLoginPassword": {
            "value": "${random_password.admin.result}"
        },
        "managedInstanceTags": {
            "value": "${var.names.product_name}-${var.names.service_name}-${random_string.mi_name.result}"
        },
        "storageAccountType": {
            "value": "${each.value.storageAccountType}"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "value": "${var.virtual_network_name}"
        },
        "virtualNetworkResourceGroupName": {
            "value": "${var.resource_group_name}"
        },
    }
    PARAMETERS
}
```

***Variables.tf***

```
variable sql_mi_defaults {
  type = any
  default = {
    managedInstanceName        = "randomcomputername"
    location                   = "eastus2"
    skuName                    = "Standard_F2"
    storageSizeInGB            = 256
    vCores                     = 8
    licenseType                = "LicenseIncluded"
    collation                  = "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
    timezoneId                 = "UTC"
    proxyOverride              = "Proxy"
    publicDataEndpointEnabled  = false
    minimalTlsVersion          = "1.2"
    administratorLogin         = "azadmin"
    administratorLoginPassword = ""
    managedInstanceTags        = ""
    storageAccountType         = "GRS"

  }
  description = <<EOT
azure sql managed instance settings (only applied to virtual machine settings managed within this module)
    managedInstanceName             = (Required) The name of the Managed Instance.
    location                        = (Required) The location of the Managed Instance
    skuName                         = (Required) Managed instance SKU. If SKU is not set, skuEdition and hardwareFamily values have to be populated."
    storageSizeInGB                 = (Required) Determines how much Storage size in GB to associate with instance. Increments of 32 GB allowed only.
    vCores                          = (Required) The number of vCores.
    licenseType                     = (Optional) Determines license pricing model. Select 'LicenseIncluded' for a regular price inclusive of a new SQL license. Select 'Base Price' for a discounted AHB price for bringing your own SQL licenses.
    collation                       = (Optional) Specifies the priority of this Virtual Machine. Possible values are Regular and Spot. Defaults to Regular. Changing this forces a new resource to be created.
    timezoneId                      = (Optional) Specifies what should happen when the Virtual Machine is evicted for price reasons when using a Spot instance. At this time the only supported value is Deallocate. Changing this forces a new resource to be created. This can only be configured when priority is set to Spot.
    proxyOverride                   = (Optional) Determines connection type for private endpoint. Proxy connection type enables proxy connectivity to Managed Instance. Redirect mode enables direct connectivity to the instance resulting in improved latency and throughput.
    publicDataEndpointEnabled       = (Optional) Determines whether public data endpoint will be enabled, required for clients outside of the connected virtual networks. Public endpoint will always default to Proxy connection mode.
    administratorLogin              = (Required) The login of the Managed Instance admin.
    administratorLoginPassword      = (Required) The password of the Managed Instance admin.
    managedInstanceTags             = (Optional) Resource tags to associate with the instance.
    storageAccountType              = (Required) Option for configuring backup storage redundancy. Selecting 'GRS' will enable 'RA-GRS'.
    virtualNetworkName              = (Required) The virtual network name. Leave empty for the default value.
    virtualNetworkResourceGroupName = (Required) The resource group where the networking resources will be created or updated. Default is the same resource group as Managed Instance.
EOT 
}
```

#### Module call (parent module)

```
# azurerm_sql_managed_instance see for more info https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/sql-managed-instance-paas-overview
module "sql_mi" {
  source = "github.com/[redacted]/azurerm-sql-managed-instance.git?ref=v2.3.1""

  resource_group_name  = module.resource_group.name
  location             = module.resource_group.location
  deployment_mode      = "Complete"
  virtual_network_name = module.virtual_network.subnet_nsg_names["iaas-outbound"]

  name = "example-output-from-each.key" # will the name of the instance be from each.key?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This:

```
for_each    = var.sql_mi_defaults
```

tells Terraform to take whatever the collection is in `var.sql_mi_defaults` and create one `azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment` resource for each item in that collection. It exposes the `each.key` and `each.value` properties within  the scope of the resource block automatically. This is all documented [here](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/for_each.html).

---

> What would be an example of deploying 1 instance?

Passing a collection of size 1 as `var.sql_mi_defaults`

> and then an example of multiple instances?

Passing a collection of size > 1 as `var.sql_mi_defaults`

Comment: thank you for taking the time to contribute.
I understand the each.value will iterate through the list of items until it finds the desired value (example: each.value.skuName) 

However I am unsure where the each.key input is defined? Could you point me in the direction of more examples?

Comment: "I understand the each.value will iterate through the list of items until it finds the desired value" is not correct. Please read the documentation I linked to.

Comment: so in the example above, each.value.skuName 
would not refer to the var.sql_mi_defaults variable input named skuName?

that is what I mean by the for_each will iterate until it finds the defined value.

Comment: It's not iterating until it finds something. It is iterating over a list, and creating a new resource for each value in the list. There is no "searching" or "finding" happening here. If `var.sql_mi_default` is a list with 3 items in it, then 3 resources are getting created. Also it is the `for_each` that is defining the iteration. `each.value` just refers to the current value in the current iteration.

Comment: No, `each.key` is simply referencing each key inside the `var.sql_mi_defaults` collection as the `for_each` iterates over that collection. There's nothing in that code snippet to indicate that it is referencing a value named "default", so I'm not sure why you think that. You would need to include the definition of `var.sql_mi_defaults` in your question for me to expand any more on that. You should also be able to easily see what this is doing by looking at your `terraform plan` output.

Comment: above I added `var.sql_mi_defaults`
there is a line named `default` which is the name of the collection, is each.key referring to that?
and if so, what if I wanted to make more than one sql managed instance, I would have to edit the `var.sql_mi_defaults` and add another collection?
-thank you for your patience! :)

Comment: `default` isn't the name of the collection, it's the default value for the variable. Please please please read some documentation to understand the basic syntax of Terraform.